# SQL database connection problem - missing databases

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am quite stressed, I am afraid I have lost my databases. I wanted to access my database from another laptop, but I finally lost the connection to my databases, and when I found it again, my databases were gone.
I hope you will be able to help me or perhaps have some encouraging leads.

I wanted to access my database from another laptop, so I tried to change my hostname from "localhost" to my IP address on MySQL Workbench. This way I could not connect to MySQL, I tried to change my hostname back to "localhost" but I could not connect either.
Finally, since I'm on a Mac, I went to System Preferences > MySQL > Initialize Database, and changed to use legacy password encryption, as suggested in a tutorial. Then I can connect to the server, but there are none of my databases, just the original "syst" database.

Comment: Databases do not get lost miraculously. My gut feeling is that you are either connecting to the wrong database instance or your user does not have access to the database in question.

Comment: My user should have access to the database, and indeed I am probably connected to the wrong database instance.... but I don't know how to find the right one. Any idea?

Comment: The databases are still in the other laptop, right? First, try `ping`ing said laptop via it's IP. Also, check in the other laptop what value the key `bind-address` in the file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` is

Comment: If you can't find the file, the query `show global variables like "bind%";` will do.

Comment: Thanks @JettoMartínez for your help. I'm not sure I did it right, but this is what I did:
When I ping my IP I get the following response: 126 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss.
I have not found a folder mysql in the folder etc.
Finally I used the line "show global variables like "bind%";" in MySQL and it returned "Empty set". I connected to MySQL via this command: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p.

Comment: I think I confused you a little. You should've ping from your computer to the laptop where the Databases are. If the result of that ping is what you said, that means you are not even able to reach the computer with the databases, so it's not possible to connect to it. The file or the query I provided should've been run/looked for in the laptop with the databases as well, not in your own.

Comment: Sorry, I think I took the wrong IP, this time I used the IPv4 from the laptop where the databases are and the ping said: "247 packets transmitted, 247 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.068/0.136/0.553/0.047 ms"
Regarding the other queries, they were all run on the laptop where the databases are located, as it is my laptop. I hope I didn't make a mistake.

Comment: So the query didn't show anything? What OS is that other laptop running?

Comment: My laptop, where the databases are located, runs on MacOS. The other one is running Linux, with a virtual machine. But I haven't done anything with the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to connect to your MySQL via command:

```
mysql -u username -ppassword (no interval after -p)
```

(bear in mind that you have to be in the bin dir of MySQL) for example using XAMPP in cmd, I can connect via the following commands:

```
cd C:\xampp\mysq\bin 
mysql -u root -ppassword
```

If you are able to connect try to reach the database via command line like this:

```
mysql -u username -ppassword --execute="select * from databasename.table"
```

or just some other query just to check if the database is still there.
This should be done on the PC(or server) where the MYSQL is installed.
If this is working you can manage to fix the issues.

Comment: I am able to connect to MySQL via this command: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p. 
But when I write the command "use databasename" it respond "ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'databasename'".

Comment: Boris, sorry for asking but are you replacing "database name" with the real name of the database?

Comment: Haha, yes, I'm not that bad at computers.